# Don't have access, prompt for no permission or agreement, iOS listing

Tags: ios

Using the tool appuploader to submit and upload steps，Don't have access, prompt for no permission or agreement, iOS listing

[[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QevSs.png)]
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYXFz.png)

Attempting multiple methods cannot solve the problem，Hope to seek help

Comment: The message tells you what to do.